# Uipageviewcontroller pager dot color - change diff color for all pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

how can i show different - different colors for all page.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
   [self setupPageControlAppearance:currentPageIndex];
   return currentPageIndex;
}

- (void)setupPageControlAppearance:(NSInteger)index
{
      UIPageControl * pageControl = [[self.view.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(class = %@)", [UIPageControl class]]] lastObject];
      pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
      pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [ColorUtils getCurrentPageColor];
}
```

its not changing the current page color due to appearance called when view added.

Note - the above code is for change current page color i tried.

but there is any way how can i achieve this -

[image]

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try on [FXPageControl](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl/blob/master/README.md) on github. It allows to customize the dot color.

Comment: Thanks for answer checking it.